# How to justify content within ion-item

Tags: ionic-framework, flexbox, ionic4

Im trying to justify content of an ion-item in ionic4. If I set `.input-wrapper { justify-content: space-around; }` from the browser console I get the desired result but what's the proper way of doing it?

```
<ion-item class="ion-justify-content-around">
  <ion-badge slot="start" class="list-badge">
    <ion-icon name="git-network-outline"></ion-icon>
  </ion-badge>
  <ion-text>Description</ion-text>
  <ion-text color="medium">500</ion-text>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

add the content in a div and slot it to center. like this:

```
<ion-item class="ion-justify-content-around">
  <div slot="center" style="width: fit-content">
    <ion-badge slot="start" class="list-badge">
      <ion-icon name="git-network-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-badge>
    <ion-text>Description</ion-text>
    <ion-text color="medium">500</ion-text>
  </div>
</ion-item>
```

Something like this.